# How to prevent multiple lines being drawn at once (swift)?

Tags: ios, swift

When I draw a line slowly, I believe it detects it as multiple lines instead of one, so it darkens the line too much.

I’m following this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/5895-uikit-drawing-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else {
            return
        }
        swiped = false
        lastPoint = touch.location(in: view)
    }

    func drawLine(from fromPoint: CGPoint, to toPoint: CGPoint) {
        //1
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return
        }
        tempImageView.image?.draw(in: view.bounds)

        //2
        context.move(to: fromPoint)
        context.addLine(to: toPoint)

        //3
        context.setLineCap(.round)
        context.setBlendMode(.normal)
        context.setLineWidth(brushWidth)
        context.setStrokeColor(color.cgColor)
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor(red: red,
                                       green: green,
                                       blue: blue,
                                       alpha: opacity).cgColor)

        //4
        context.strokePath()

        //5
        tempImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        tempImageView.alpha = opacity
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else {
            return
        }
        //6
        swiped = true
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: view)
        drawLine(from: lastPoint, to: currentPoint)

        //7
        lastPoint = currentPoint
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if !swiped {
            //draw a single point
            drawLine(from: lastPoint, to: lastPoint)
        }
        //merge tempImageView into mainImageView
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mainImageView.frame.size)
        mainImageView.image?.draw(in: view.bounds, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)
        tempImageView?.image?.draw(in: view.bounds, blendMode: .normal, alpha: opacity)
        mainImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        tempImageView.image = nil
    }
```

When I draw over it, it is hard to see that it darkens the point where they intersect. I would like it to be more noticeable. In this picture, opacity is set to 0.5.

[image]

The areas that have dots on the lines is where I drew really quickly. Where it is solid is where I drew the lines slowly. I would like for all lines to look like the quickly-drawn lines — minus the dots of course.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/Awalz/SwiftyDraw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the blend mode of draw line context to `.copy` for get the same color

From

```
    //3
    context.setBlendMode(.normal)
```

to

```
    //3
    context.setBlendMode(.copy)
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the original problem. Now, whenever I change opacity to something < 1, it makes all the other lines change to the same opacity. But then if I change opacity back to one, it makes the lines go to their original opacity. Here, I made lines from 1.0 to 0.5 (I’m tired.. don’t ask why I put 10 and 5) https://ibb.co/d4RpytG. Here is 1.0 to 0.1 https://ibb.co/sPsfYNx. I made it 0 and they all went away. Then I changed it to 1.0 and they reappeared. https://ibb.co/C0Pmp5m